# Crear Array en un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

estoy migrando un procedimiento almacenado de oracle a Sql server y tengo este inconveniente.

Resulta que ocupan un varray dentro del código. No se la manera de hacerlo en SQL. Buscando por diferentes páginas, algunos recomiendan que se haga una tabla y se realice un SELECT, el problema es que me piden que no cambie la estructura del SP y que sea lo más parecida posible.

```
 Type oCampos Is Table of Varchar(40);

 vDatoPoliza oDatoPoliza;
 vDato       oDato;
 vCampo      SET @oCampos = oCampos();

 vHeader     SET @oCampos = oCampos();
 vMonCpo     SET @oCampos = oCampos();
```

Agradezco sus comentarios y sugerencias. Saludos.

Comment: En SQL Server no podrás declarar un `Array` porque no existe. Lo que investigaste es el deber ser, crear una tabla y obtener o insertar datos directamente ahí.

Comment: [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql#a-declaring-a-variable-of-type-table) tienes un ejemplo para crear una variable tipo tabla. Y a partir de eso usas un select o un [cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) para extraer los datos de tu "array" tabla. Cabe destacar que una variable tipo tabla no cambia la estructura de la base de datos (ya que es una tabla "Temporal"). Pd: No entiendo el código que pusiste, si supiera exactamente lo que quieres usaría un ejemplo.